# Iframe Responsive Design Not Scaling Correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an iframe to a Google map on my site:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=EXAMPLE" style="top:0px; position:fixed; float:left; width:35%; height:400px;"></iframe>
```

and I have a table displaying data to the left of that map:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesorter7af52c677e1d6" width="500" border="1" style="display:block; float:left; width: 65%;" role="grid">
</table>
```

for views above 1050px this works well. The data table takes up 65% of viewing area as intended and the map 35% in the upper right. Once viewing < 1050px though the iframe seems to only scale slightly and begins covering the HTML table more and more as viewing area reduces. The content in the iframe also doesn't scale, maybe this is a side effect of Google responsive design though(see below)?

View at +1050px (and intended view overall):

[image: intended view]

View at 500px (overlapping map):

[image]

map is only showing 50% of content originally displayed (between interstate 91 and Augusta), share option and info block also have been removed (I think the latter is from Google responsive)

If data is needed please let me know. I think this is as minimal as needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesorter7af52c677e1d6" width="500" border="1" style="display:block; float:left; width: 65%;" role="grid">
        </table>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=EXAMPLE" style="top:0px; position:fixed; float:left; width:35%; height:400px;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Rendered styles:
Table:
[image: Table]

iframe:
[image]

Comment: Try adding a div around table with fixed width and `overflow-x :auto`, so that the table becomes responsive.

Comment: @AbhaySrivastav The table is responsive if the viewport is > 1050px. Do you mean I need an additional div for responsiveness below that? I tried `<div style="overflow-x :auto"><table id="myTable"...></table></div><iframe...`  but that put the iframe overlaying the table. I'm not sure how I'd use a fixed width and still have responsiveness

Comment: Maybe the table can't be squeezed beyond a certain width because of its content. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp This might help.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? I think the Iframe doesn't scale bacause of the website it's displaying. If you want to show the same area on resize you need to scale the website the iframe is displaying.

Comment: @DavidMachado I want a 2 column display with the left panel taking up 65% consistently and the right taking up 35%.

Comment: Do you want the table and the iframe to be shown side by side even at viewport width <=500px? @user3783243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `table` in a `div` and remove the `fixed` position from the `iframe` to achieve the 65-35 layout in all screens.

Although I would personally recommend switching to column layout in smaller screens to provide better data viewing.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: scroll;
}

table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #121212;
}

iframe {
  width: 35%;
  height: 400px;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 65%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesorter7af52c677e1d6" role="grid">
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the `float:left;`s as well, and give a `right:0` to the div I wanted fixed on the right panel.